# c++ char question

Tags: c++, data-structures, types, char

so I'm implementing this chess program on C++ and I'm trying to integrate to winboard protocol...one of the functions that they say I need to write to do so should have the following signature:

```
char *MoveToText(MOVE move);            // converts the move from your internal format to text like e2e2, e1g1, a7a8q.
```

my question is....the text formats are something like e2e2....but the return type of that function is char...and as far as I can understand it, char is just one single character....

so how come are they telling me to use this signature?

or am I mistaken and in fact char can also store multiple characters such as e2e2, e1g1 etc?

Comment: Do you have a documentation URL that you're referencing by chance?

Comment: I just got it from this thread: http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=51739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, in C, a char* points to an array of characters. C treats arrays of characters as strings, terminated by a null byte.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ASCII/UTF-8 strings are null-terminated arrays of characters? There's no requirement for a null on the end of a char[] (although it is a common convention)

Comment: @Phil A string is just an array of characters, but I guess that it is null terminated makes it a string instead of simply an array. But if you try to use a non-null terminated char[] in a function that expects a string, you'll either get a segfault or garbage, or other unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The return is a char* or a c-style string =)

Answer (score 1):

`char *` is a pointer on char - address of sequence of characters.

Answer (score 1):

It returns pointer to char, which is basically a c-string.

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html